# Array is of fixed size (imported from JSON file object)

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to create a new JSON deployment file from an existing object.. but the new object wont allow me to add additional parameters

```
Export-AzResourceGroup -ResourceGroupName $InputObject.ResourceGroupName -Resource $InputObject.id -IncludeParameterDefaultValue -IncludeComments -Path ./InputObject.json

$NewObject=Get-Content -Raw ./InputObject.json | ConvertFrom-Json  

$NewObject.resources.zones={1,2,3}
```

#InvalidOperation: The property 'zones' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.

```
$newObject.resources.Add('zones')
```

MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "Add" with "1" argument(s): "Collection was of a fixed size."

How to add additional resource entries into the array?

(goal is to export an existing AppGateway, delete it and recreate it with zone redundancy)

Comment: Arrays are immutable so you'll have to create a new array for each item you get. You can use += to do this.

Comment: You can use `+=` operator to append to an array of fixed size (which actually creates a new array). E. g. `$newObject.resources += @{ zones = 1,2,3 }`. This is just a guess, as you didn't give before/after samples of the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types) of the items you get .

See `<<Object>>.GetType()` , `System.Collections.Hashtable` , `Add-Member` and `System.Collections.Generic.List[object]` .

Comment: $newobject.resources.properties | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "zones" -NotePropertyValue $Zones -Force

Comment: Add-Member is very slow though